# Como fazer Jframe com JmenuBar chamando outro JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Olá, tenho uma classe principal que está funcionando mas na hora de clicar no menu Cadastro e depois cliente ele não chama a outra tela JFrame CadastroClienteUI.

Aqui está o trecho que era para chamar o outro JFrame que está implementado em outra classe..

```
//criando o MenuItem cliente para executar o cadastro de clientes
    JMenuItem menuItemCadastro = new JMenuItem("Cadastro");
    menuItemCadastro.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            new CadastroClienteUI();
        }
    });
```

aqui esta a classe CadastroClienteUI

```
public class CadastroClienteUI {

public CadastroClienteUI(){

    final JFrame frameCadastroCliente = new JFrame("Cadastro de Cliente");
    frameCadastroCliente.setSize(400,240);
    frameCadastroCliente.setVisible(true);
    frameCadastroCliente.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JLabel rotuloNome = new JLabel();
    rotuloNome.setText("Nome: ");
    panel.add(rotuloNome);

    final JTextField textFieldNome = new JTextField(30);
    panel.add(textFieldNome);

    JLabel rotuloTelefone = new JLabel();
    rotuloTelefone.setText("Telefone: ");
    panel.add(rotuloTelefone);

    final JTextField textFieldTelefone = new JTextField(30);
    panel.add(textFieldTelefone);

    JLabel rotuloRG = new JLabel();
    rotuloRG.setText("RG: ");
    panel.add(rotuloRG);

    final JTextField textFieldRG = new JTextField(30);
    panel.add(textFieldRG);

    JLabel rotuloCPF = new JLabel();
    rotuloCPF.setText("CPF: ");
    panel.add(rotuloCPF);

    final JTextField textFieldCPF = new JTextField(30);
    panel.add(textFieldCPF);

    JLabel rotuloEndereco = new JLabel();
    rotuloEndereco.setText("Endereço: ");
    panel.add(rotuloEndereco);

    final JTextField textFieldEndereco = new JTextField(30);
    panel.add(textFieldEndereco);

    JButton buttonSalvar = new JButton ("Salvar");
    buttonSalvar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            //InsereCliente insereCliente = new InsereCliente();
            JDBCClienteDAO insereCliente = new JDBCClienteDAO();

            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
            cliente.setNome(textFieldNome.getText());
            cliente.setTelefone(textFieldTelefone.getText());
            cliente.setRG(textFieldRG.getText());
            cliente.setCPF(textFieldCPF.getText());
            cliente.setEndereco(textFieldEndereco.getText());

            insereCliente.gravaCliente(cliente);
        }
    });

    panel.add(buttonSalvar);

    JButton buttonCancelar = new JButton("Cancelar");
    buttonCancelar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        frameCadastroCliente.dispose();
        }
    });

    panel.add(buttonCancelar);

    frameCadastroCliente.setContentPane(panel);
    frameCadastroCliente.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Simplificando, não faltou new CadastroClienteUI().setVisible(true);?

Comment: Não aceita, tem que criar o método setVisible();

Comment: Adicione na pergunta o código da classe CadastroClienteUI.

Comment: adicionei o código da classe CadastroClienteUI já

Comment: Tirando as classes que você customizou, aqui funcionou normalmente.